# Magento Observer not firing in order when using <depends>

Tags: event-observer, newsletter, dependency

The problem I'm having is that when observing `customer_save_after`, I try and get the customer's newsletter subscription status, and it gets the value before the newsletter subscription status is saved.

Example: I click subscribe in the account dashboard and save, when I look at the logs, it says I am unsubscribed (from the last time I saved it), when I save it again, it will grab the previously saved status. Then I uncheck the box and click save, it will say I am subscribed as that was the last status before I unsubscribed.

I saw that `Mage_Newsletter` is also observing the same event. I set a depends in XML on `Mage_Newsletter` to ensure the configuration is loaded after that module, however this doesn't seem to fix the issue. I've refreshed my cache and even tried setting the depends to `Mage_XmlConnect`, as to ensure it is loaded much later in the xml stack. I'm all out of ideas here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Local modules are always loaded after core modules, so you seem to have drawn the wrong conclusions. Without some code it's hard to say, where the mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you should be able to set the depends on `Mage_Newsletter` and then your observer will happen after, either that or you could call your module `X_X` or something so it should be loaded last (note: the second idea is not the best solution).

You could also listen to the event `newsletter_subscriber_save_after` this will be fired after the subscriber action is saved.

Comment: Yea to call it X_X means refactoring a bit of code. I'll have to dump the xml stack and figure out what is happening. Either its a local issue or Mage is just being a punk. My module namespace starts with a V and the module P anyway so I dont think its an issue of naming convention.

Comment: I'll have to look at it monday, day off today, heh.